# How to calculate average grade over roads from DXF input?

Tags: qgis, road

I receive a dxf file containing percentage grades of a road. It comes from lidar data and it's very accurate. The problem is percentage is included into points and the line is just a line. What I would like to achieve is to calculate longer stretches of a road and get the average grade.

[image]

[image]

I don't know where to start.

Comment: Just an idea: on the second screenshot it seems you have line intersections corresponding to the point data. You could try using "line intersections" to create the required points there, then create an approriate buffer from these points to include the point data. Transfer the data from the point data to the buffer then to the intersection points with "join by location". Then you can save this data into excel and should be able to trace whichever profile you want.

Comment: Another idea, which could perhaps work: you could isolate the point data with the elevation (select with an expression using "field" NOT LIKE '%+%' AND "field" NOT LIKE '%\%%') then create a TIN with it (SAGA) or IDW (GRASS), and then use the terrain profile plugin with the sections for which you want the slope.